# installing package from R-forge fails

Tags: r, r-forge

When trying to install a package from R-forge (https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=343), I follow the instruction entering

```
install.packages("CHAID", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

but I get:

> package ‘CHAID’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)

I do not understand why, as the build status of the package is "Current" and my R is the most recent.

Edit: As cleraly stated, the build status of the package (of this question) is Current. As clearly stated on the supposed duplicated question, the build status (for (the package of) that question) is failure. The answer to that question does not apply to mine.
I do not believe therefore that the question is a duplicated.

Comment: https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5953&group_id=34&atid=194

Comment: Thanks, but apparently the package of this question was updated a couple of days ago, while the package in question here has not been updated for more than a year. So I am not convinced it is the same problem

Comment: Then it's offtopic because it's a question for the R-Forge admin

Comment: The answer on "the supposed duplicated question" shows you how to checkout, build,and install the package regardless of whether R-Forge built the right version.

Comment: Sure, but my problem is not about installing the package, which I already did, my problem is about the recommended way not working, for I wanted others to install this package easily.I do agrre it is bestly asked elsewhere, just wanted to make sure I was not making a stupid mistake.